# What is energy's basic shape/form?

Tags: energy

I have been thinking about how earthquakes, light, sound, water tension, and movement work. I do not have a degree in physics, nor have I taken it (yet), but I am willing to learn.

To summarize my question

1. Newton's 3rd law states **all actions have an opposite and equal reaction**. So, if we live in 3 dimensions; energy must act 3 dimensionally right? So, what is energy's basic shape/form? cubic? spherical? cone?

I will try to explain why I theorize energy (i.e. movement, heat, sound, ...) has a shape (Prepare for a lot of edits):

A1. energy is invisible, but we can see the reaction i.e. wind (in this case energy) moving leaves (the reaction)

A2. Every reaction has an opposite and equal reaction i.e. I jump up (action) gravity pushes me down (reaction)

A3. If every ripple of energy has an epicenter/point of origin (i.e. earthquake, light, sound) **what shape does the "energy" take when in movement, because the movement is a reaction?**

Comment: Can you please explain more about why you think energy has a shape? That seems similar to thinking that numbers have shapes. Energy isn’t an object but a (numerical) property of a system.

Comment: I tried to explain my question for accurately, thank you for your patience! :)

Comment: In my opinion, the more you theorize about physics before taking physics, the harder it will be to learn it. You will have to unlearn most of your preconceived ideas because they will be incompatible with the mainstream physics that you’ll be taught.

Comment: A3 doesn't mean anything. Energy is also present in an object moving with zero acceleration through the vacuum of space. It is also present in the mutual attraction between the Earth and a ball sitting on the top shelf. And why are you trying to use Newton's Laws of Motion to talk about the movement of energy? They're not the same thing. You're equating "movement" of energy with mechanical movement. Laymen words aren't precise and should not be taken literally nor should conclusions be extrapolated from laymen usage of such words when talking about nuanced matters in physics.

Comment: Energy has no shape. Just like, say, sound has no shape. Or like colour has no shape. Such "abstract" and non-tangible concepts or properties no not necessarily have a shape.

Comment: Also, note that jumping is not the action force with gravity being the reaction force. Gravity pulls down in you even if you aren't jumping. Rather, when you jump by applying a force downwards into the ground, then the ground is applying an equal force upwards in you. We call that force the normal force. That normal force is larger than gravity and thus this normal force is causing you to jump up.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, there are a lot of things to talk about here, heh.

The basic thing to start with is this difference. A physical quantity can be like conventional “stuff” in three different ways:

1. It can be volumetric—it can occupy a volume of space. This was the oldest definition of “stuff” that Renée Descartes used.
2. It can be objectively measurable. So, imagine that you have a large clear plastic box where a child keeps his or her toys. This says that even if people are moving past this box in a car or so, everybody agrees on how many toys are in the box.
3. It can be a conserved quantity. This means that maybe two different people measure the number of toys in the box differently, but they agree that if you watch for toys going into or out of the opening in the box, then that is everything you need to figure out how much stuff is in the box—at least, combined with an initial count. So two people disagree on how many toys there are and maybe even disagree on when a toy is going into or coming out of the box, but those toys are still a “stuff” because they have to flow into/out of the box, they are not spontaneously changing inside the box.

In some ways (1) is a stronger criterion than (2) and subsumes it, at least pre-relativity: you can use the volume the stuff takes up as an objective measure. An example of (1) is sand, another example is liquid water at standard temperature and pressure over short enough times to ignore evaporation. In turn (2) is in some ways stronger than (3), as you can draw imaginary “boxes” going into/out of the box and objectively measure the stuff flowing in or out. (With that said you do need to be a little careful here, as one can weaken “stuff” to allow that stuff can be created from non-stuff sometimes. So, sand might be turned into diamond, chemical reactions might produce water molecules from hydrogen and oxygen gas, nuclear reactions might produce hydrogen from a free neutron.)

An example of (2) that is not (1) might be more like maybe the points on a sports scoreboard, they do not take up space but anyone passing by that scoreboard can see how many points each team has. Not a great example, because points are routinely created by the rules of the game, but maybe it helps to visualize.

Energy and momentum are not “stuff” in senses (1) or (2), but only in sense (3). Two different people will routinely calculate different amounts of energy in a box, especially if they are moving relative to each other. But, energy is conserved, meaning that whatever you think the numbers are, the amount in a box mostly just changes because the energy flows into/out of the box somehow. So you can pretend it is stuff in a very practical sense, just like you would measure water going into a bucket by looking at the rate in which it is dripping or being poured into it. But it lacks that objectivity thought you might be familiar with in thinking about other sorts of stuff, like sand and rice and water.

The question of what shape something has is really only applicable to type-(1) stuff and even then is somewhat limited. For type-(3) stuff, the question itself does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I am strictly referring to Newtonian mechanics as suggested in the question.I am not taking into account - energy-mass equivalence principle and its related Physics.

---

There is no physical existence of energy.Energy is just a mathematical concept introduced by physicists to study systems easily by the help of 'measuring scales'.

The basic definition says energy is the capacity to do work.

Work, in Physics, happens when a system can displace under application of a force.

Energy is the measure of how much the body can displace under its given circumstances.

---

For example :
When we say gravitational Potential Energy of a body at greater height is higher,we mean that it can displace to a greater extent under the same force of gravity.

Notice how assigning values of Gravitational Potential Energy at different heights make our interpretations much easier and logical.

Comment: Note that the potential energy of an object depends on your choice of a reference point and its kinetic energy depends on your choice of a coordinate system.

Comment: @R.W.Bird In other words, it helps us visualise and predict phenomenon in the easiest way possible.

Comment: Our current modeling of the physical world seems to work for us.  Who knows how it may evolve in the future?